# How to Map a string and char pair to a string using a std::map?

Tags: c++, string, mapping, stdmap, std-pair

I am trying to take a std::pair and map it to a std::string using a std::map. The way it works being given a pair consisting of a char and a string, map it to a particular string.

This setup so far works just fine(compiler accepts it):

```
std::map<std::pair<char, std::string>, std::string> mymap;
std::map<std::pair<char, std::string>, std::string>::iterator it;
```

But when i try to do this:

```
mymap['a', "Q1"] = "Q4";
mymap['b', "Q2"] = "Q3";
mymap['c', "Q3"] = "Q2";
mymap['d', "Q4"] = "Q1";
```

it comes back as this error which I do not understand:

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [3]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

which is the error associated under the left bracket of each of the four lines of code(where a red squiggly appears)

can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do it like mymap[{'a', "Q1"}] = "Q4";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [] operator on map doesn't take two items. It takes just one. In your case it's expecting a std::pair object. So something like this will work:

```
mymap[std::pair<char, std::string>('c', "Q1")] = "Q4";
```

You might want to make a typedef for your pair class:

```
using myPair = std::pair<char, std::string>;
mymap[myPair('c', "Q1")] = "Q4";
```

Answer (score 1):

the `[]` operator for the `std::map` accepts only one argument, whereas you provided two. Since you want to use an object of type `std::pair`, you should make an `std::pair` object with your `char` and `std::string`. You can do it by enclosing them in `{}`:

```
mymap[{'a', "Q1"}] = "Q4";
mymap[{'b', "Q2"}] = "Q3";
mymap[{'c', "Q3"}] = "Q2";
mymap[{'d', "Q4"}] = "Q1";
```

You could also provide an object definition each time you try yo access the elements:

```
mymap[std::pair<char, std::string>('a', "Q1")] = "Q4";
mymap[std::pair<char, std::string>('b', "Q2")] = "Q3";
mymap[std::pair<char, std::string>('c', "Q3")] = "Q2";
mymap[std::pair<char, std::string>('d', "Q4")] = "Q1";
```

But the first option in my opinion is better and less errorprone.